# PHP cURL cannot download image, returns 503 error

Tags: php, nginx, curl, kibana

I am having problems with cURL in my PHP code to download an image, when I use it from a terminal I get the image but when it's executed in my code I get an empty file owned by apache:apache. I'm wondering if it could be proxy problem. My code is :

```
function download_image($image_url, $image_file){
    $fp = fopen ($image_file, 'w+'); 
    $verbose = fopen('curl-debug.log', 'w+');             

    $ch = curl_init($image_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myuser:mypassword");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json, charset=utf-8'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);          
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10000); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);   
    curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);                             
    fclose($fp);                                 
}
```

The URL I try to cURL is a PNG from a Kibana Dashboard. Below is the output of the cURL verbose. I replaced some code with "X" but it's the right IPs etc.

```
* About to connect() to my-site port 80 (#14)
*   Trying XX.XX.XX.XXX...
* Connected to my-site (XX.XX.XX.XXX) port 80 (#14)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'XXXXXXX'
> GET /kibana/api/reporting/jobs/download/xxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1^M
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Host: my-site^M
Accept: */*^M
Content-Type: application/json, charset=utf-8^M
^M
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable^M
< Server: nginx/1.12.2^M
< Date: Thu, 05 Nov 2020 11:03:47 GMT^M
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8^M
< Content-Length: 7^M
< Connection: keep-alive^M
< retry-after: 30^M
< accept-ranges: none^M
< kbn-name: http://my-site^M
< kbn-license-sig: [REDACTED]
< kbn-xpack-sig: [REDACTED]
< cache-control: no-cache^M
< ^M
* Connection #14 to host my-site left intact
```

Also, I go through nginx so maybe that's the problem ? Do you know why I get this 503 error in return of cURL ?

Edit: The output of the "unix" cURL used in command line in a terminal is below

```
*   Trying XX.XX.XX.XXX...
* Connected to my-site (XX.XX.XX.XXX) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user '[REDACTED]'
> GET /kibana/api/reporting/jobs/download/xXXxxXXXXX HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic [REDACTED]
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: my-site
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.12.2
< Date: Mon, 09 Nov 2020 13:29:28 GMT
< Content-Type: image/png
< Content-Length: 76542
< Connection: keep-alive
< content-disposition: inline; filename="dashboard.png"
< accept-ranges: none
< kbn-name: http://my-site
< kbn-license-sig: [REDACTED]
< kbn-xpack-sig: [REDACTED]
< cache-control: no-cache
< X-Cache-Status: MISS
< X-Handled-By: xxxxx:5601
```

Comment: Please share with us the verbose output of your `curl` command line statement (the one which works as you said).

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Would it work if you used cURL from the shell, without PHP?

Comment: `when I use it from a terminal I get the image` - do you mean you run `curl` from the command line, or you're running some PHP cli?  Is the terminal on the same machine that your PHP code is running on?

Comment: Yes when I launch it from a terminal it's the "unix" curl not the PHP one and from the same machine, just not with the same user (as PHP seems to run it with apache). I will curl with verbose from terminal to see if there are differences but since it's not the PHP curl I don't think it will help me! But I'll try, thanks for suggestion!

Comment: you added the output of CURLOPT_VERBOSE, that is a good start, now add the output of `curl -v (...)` as well - i actually have a theory about useragent, but show us the -v log too

Comment: I added it to the original post if you want to look, I'm not seeing any differences tho...

Comment: @Docrom if you don't see any differences, then you're not looking closely enough. only 1 of them has a `User-Agent` :)

Answer (score 0):

you're probably interacting with a website that blocks all requests lacking a `User-Agent` header. not too uncommon, wikipedia.org is one famous example (they block all requests lacking a user-agent)

by default, curl the cli program has a user-agent, it looks like `User-Agent: curl/7.29.0`, but libcurl by contrast has no default user-agent, and neither does your script, as is evident by your verbose logs. try adding

```php
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Docrom's awesome image download script");
```

or if you just wanna fake it, maybe just

```php
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl/7.29.0");
```

(or perhaps something more fancy with curl_version() & co)

Comment: Hi hanshenrik, I tried adding the user-agent thing but I still have a 503 Service Unavailable error and no image is downloaded. I checked the libcurl verbose and the User Agent is set.

Edit: Another thing I don't have in my libcurl verbose compared to the terminal one is the "X-Handled-By" thingy, any idea what is this for ?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I finally found what the problem was and it is actually funny (almost flipped a table tho).

Kibana is slow generating the PNG from the Dashboard so I had to add a sleep of 30 seconds in my PHP code to give Kibana time and then download the PNG. And it works perfectly now...